# Consuming WCF Data Service EF , Failed to SaveChange()

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, dataservice, wcf-data-services-client

I am consuming WCF Data Service as Following:

```
 DataMan.ContextWrapper context = new DataMan.ContextWrapper(new Uri("http://localhost:2060/PCM/DataMan.svc/rest/"));
            DataMan.Report newReport = DataMan.Report.CreateReport("123123123123", DateTime.Now, "999.199905171156550187000.25");

            newReport.Title = "tt";
            newReport.StudyAcDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-05-04 12:09:00");
            newReport.Body = "asdasd";
            newReport.Auther = "ali.h";
            newReport.ApproverComment = "cm";
            newReport.Approver = "admin";
            context.AddToReports(newReport);
            DataServiceResponse response = context.SaveChanges();
```

but after calling `SaveChange()` I have got the following error:

> > The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Incoming message for operation 'ProcessRequestForMessage' (contract 'IRequestHandler' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Xml'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details.

and my WCF Data Service is as following:

```
 public class ContextWrapper : DataAccessDbContext
{
    public ContextWrapper() : base("connection string")
    {

    }
}

[JSONPSupportBehavior]
public class DataMan : EntityFrameworkDataService<ContextWrapper>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Studies", EntitySetRights.None);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true; // TODO - Remove for production?
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
    protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
        base.HandleException(args);
    }
}
```

I also implemented and configured `WebContentTypeMapper` to bypass mentioned Error as following:

```
 public class ContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return WebContentFormat.Raw;
    }
}
```

Custom binding:

```
   <binding name="XmlMapper">
      <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="MARCO.SOA.PCMServiceLib.ContentTypeMapper,MARCO.SOA.PCMServiceLib.Core"/>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Service endpoint:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="Commom2.Behavior" name="MARCO.SOA.PCMServiceLib.DataMan">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="Rest.Behavior" binding="webHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="XmlMapper" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2060/PCM/DataMan.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

but it still get exception, I think something went wrong with my configuration.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anybody knows how I can change Body format of WCF restful service programmatically ?

Comment: I really don't know what I should do...., If there is need to more details please tell me to update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, after much trouble I finally solved the problem,
 so we need to initiate `factory` property for `serviceActivation`

So my relative address was:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
.
.
.
   <add relativeAddress="DataMan.svc" service="MARCO.SOA.PCMServiceLib.DataMan"/>
.
.
.
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

and I have changed it to

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
.
.
.
    <add relativeAddress="DataMan.svc" service="MARCO.SOA.PCMServiceLib.DataMan" factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
.
.
.
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

now everything is now working nice.

more info about [DataServiceHostFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataservicehostfactory(v=vs.113).aspx)

Note:
By this we don't need to override `GetMessageFormatForContentType` of `WebContentTypeMapper` and force it to return `WebContentFormat.Raw` or another content format and don't need any `customBinding` in config file.

Thanks to all.